# How to input the dropdown-item inside the navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have created a header , with inside a navbar

I would like to have an element wihich become a dropdown-menu. But I don't understand why is not appearing my item.

I see on the link, that it seem easy:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Pills with dropdowns

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <header>
```

ITEC-EP

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Applications<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="wiki.html">Wiki</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

I dont have any error message.
When i click to my drop down menu, nothing happens. The inner element are not appearing.

I am trying to not use css, but only bootstrap. I chosed to use this template:
https://bootswatch.com/materia/

What am I mistaking?
In the future how can i debug in the developer mode in mozilla?

Comment: I would guess you're missing bootstrap.js, popper.js or jquery

Comment: Thank you man!

You were right :)

I did not used 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the issue is not having the correct javaScript packages installed. I had this when I first used Bootstrap, and I was missing popper.js